# Encountered a weird warning : operation on 'C' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

Tags: c, printf, compiler-warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char A = 0xEB;
    unsigned char B = 0xE5;
    unsigned char C = 0x0; 
    printf("%#x\n",A^B);
    
    printf("%d %#x",C = A^B,C = A^B);//This line cause the warning

    //*[Warning] operation on 'C' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]*
}
```

My compiler: TDM-GCC 9.2.0

What caused this warning?

Comment: The order of the evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. But you are trying to assign the variable C the value of which can depend on the order of the evaluation of arguments. So the compiler says that this can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no guarantee regarding the order the two assignments to C will be applied as they're assignment expressions used as function arguments.

Comment: Does order of evaluation really matter here? The point being, there's two assignment to the same variable without a seq point in between.

Comment: @MEDLDN That is an overstatement! using `=` is perfectly fine, until it breaks the program integrity. :)

Answer (score 1):

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 2    If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.<sup>84)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 84) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
>           i = ++i + 1;
>           a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
>           i = i + 1;
>           a[i] = i;
> ```

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

In the statement

```
printf("%d %#x",C = A^B,C = A^B);
```

the expressions `C = A^B` have a side effect (assign a new value to `C`) and they are unsequenced relative to each other (function arguments are not guaranteed to be evaluated from left to right, right to left, or any other order, and their evaluations may even be interleaved), hence the warning.  Even though `C` is being assigned the same value both times, the behavior is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the same variable twice, without having a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) in between, hence the warning. To avoid this, do

```
 C = A^B;  // determine the value of `C`
 printf("%d %#x",C ,C); // just use `C` as argument
```

To clarify, having it either

```
printf("%d %#x",C = A^B,C);
```

or

```
printf("%d %#x",C ,C = A^B);
```

won't work, as the order of evaluation of function argument is unspecified. You need to have the value calculated before and use the variable which stored the result as the argument to `printf()`.